# Plot rendered in R Markdown doesn't match plot rendered in console

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have an R Markdown document I'm using as a notebook. In this document I have a series of plots of trig functions. One of these, for the tangent function, looks as expected when generating the plot in the console, but is wildly different when the same code is executed when knitting the R Markdown document.

Reproducible example:

````
```
library(tidyverse)

degrees_bounds <- seq(-720, 720, by = 1)
radians <- map(degrees_bounds, \(x){x * pi / 180}) %>% unlist() %>% round(., 4)            # check
pi_radians <- radians / pi %>% round(., 4)
sine_col <- map(pi_radians, \(x){sin(x)}) %>% unlist() %>% round(., 4)                          # check
cosine_col <- map(pi_radians, \(x){cos(x)}) %>% unlist() %>% round(., 4)                        # check
tangent_col <- (sine_col/cosine_col) %>% unlist() %>% round(., 4)                               # check
cotangent_col <- (cosine_col/sine_col) %>% unlist() %>% round(., 4)                             # check
secant_col <- (1/cosine_col) %>% unlist() %>% round(., 4)                                       # check
cosecant_col <- (1/sine_col) %>% unlist() %>% round(., 4)                                       # check

trig_table <- bind_cols(
    degrees_bounds,
    radians,
    pi_radians, 
    sine_col, 
    cosine_col, 
    tangent_col, 
    cotangent_col, 
    secant_col, 
    cosecant_col)  %>% 
    rename("degrees" = "...1", 
           "radians" = "...2", 
           "pi_radians" = "...3",
           "sine" = "...4",
           "cosine" = "...5",
           "tangent" = "...6",
           "cotangent" = "...7",
           "secant" = "...8",
           "cosecant" = "...9")

### Plot three tangent lines    
    tangent_graph_1_tbl <- trig_table %>% 
    filter(tangent != -Inf) %>% 
    filter(tangent != Inf) %>% 
    filter(pi_radians > 0.5) %>% 
    filter(pi_radians < 1.5)
            
    tangent_graph_2_tbl <- trig_table %>% 
    filter(tangent != -Inf) %>% 
    filter(tangent != Inf) %>% 
    filter(pi_radians > -0.5) %>% 
    filter(pi_radians < 0.5) 
    
    tangent_graph_3_tbl <- trig_table %>% 
    filter(tangent != -Inf) %>% 
    filter(tangent != Inf) %>% 
    filter(pi_radians > 1.5) %>% 
    filter(pi_radians < 2.5) 
    
    tangent_plot <- ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data = tangent_graph_1_tbl, aes(x = pi_radians, y = tangent), color = "red") + 
    geom_line(data = tangent_graph_2_tbl, aes(x = pi_radians, y = tangent), color = "red") + 
    geom_line(data = tangent_graph_3_tbl, aes(x = pi_radians, y = tangent), color = "red") + 
    scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 9) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-10, 10)) + 
    labs(
        title = "Tangent Function",
        subtitle = "Range -0.5 Radians to 2.5 Radians",
        caption = TeX(r'(Curves extend to \pm infinity)'), 
        x = "Angle in Pi Radians"
    )

tangent_plot
```
````

[image: Appearance in RStudio console]

[image: Appearance in RMarkdown document]

Comment: Based on your code the second graph is correct. Hence, the most likely reason you get two different charts is that you used some different data for your first chart.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, Stephan, but the same data (as shown in the reproducible example) and the same code (ditto) produced the two different plots. The only difference in how each was produced is that the one with three curves was generated in the console, while the one with two curves was produced by knitting the R Markdown document containing the same data and code.